# RecyclerView itemView OnGlobalLayoutListener doesn't fire for all itemViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` in whose view holder constructor I'm adding an onGlobalLayoutListener as follows

```
public CustomViewHolder(final View itemView, Context context) {
    super(itemView, context);
    itemView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          @Override
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Get height here
          }
     });
}
```

This fires for all `itemViews` that are visible on the screen, but as I scroll the recyclerView, it doesn't fire for the `itemViews` that start to appear on the screen. Why is that? How can I capture this listener for those items?

Comment: override `onLayout` of your `itemView`

Answer (score 18):

Register an OnLayoutChangeListener like this:

```
imageViewAvatar.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
       imageViewAvatar.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
       // Get height here
}
});
```

Comment: Give me reasons why I should use this instead of `ViewTreeObserver`, please.

Comment: You may find this post helpful https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/understanding-android-views-dimensions-set/

Comment: From that article: [View.doOnLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/package-summary#doonlayout)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnPreDrawListener` instead of `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on `ViewTreeObserver`

```
    public CustomViewHolder(final View itemView, Context context) {
        super(itemView, context);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onPreDraw() {
                vto.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                // Get height here
                return true;
              }
         });
    }
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
        val vto = viewTreeObserver
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(
            object: ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
                override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                    //Your code
                    return true
                }
            }
        )
```